# Which is correct here: "who has" or "with"?

Tags: grammaticality

Which of these sentences is correct?

> I'm a musician with an unhealthy addiction.

OR

> I'm a musician who has an unhealthy addiction.

Or are they both correct? Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Both correct, but the former sounds more natural here.

Answer (score 4):

They're both fine. You could switch it up and use both for the sake of repetition and variation. One just uses a relative clause to describe the speaker where the other uses a prepositional phrase.

MUSICIAN: I am a musician who has an unhealthy addiction--I write so much music that I don't get any sleep.

2ND MUSICIAN: I am also a musician with an unhealthy addiction--I write so much music that I forget to eat.

Since the relative pronoun is redundant and is not really doing much of anything outside of the structure of the sentence, the preposition strikes me as a better place to start for style points. While it would be more concise and maybe a little more natural to use the *with*, in the examples above, I start with the *who* so that the second speaker isn't upstaging the first.

This might be a good time to review other types of relative clauses:

**Non-restrictive clause**: The musician, who has an unhealthy addition, is adamant about following his 12 step program.

**Restrictive clause**: The musician who has an unhealthy addition will crash and burn.

Comment: +1 for an excellent example showing they're actually so interchangeable that you can use both in the same sequence without it even being particularly noticeable.